# pandas pct_change returns wrong value when sorting by column

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot get my pandas dataframe to correctly put an output for pct_change() using the code as follows.

```
for column in df:
    print(df[column].pct_change())
```

However if I use the simple one line below there is no issue

```
print(df.pct_change())
```

If this issue is similar to [pandas pct_change() function returning wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36285546/pandas-pct-change-function-returning-wrong-value) however the solution there involves updating numexpr and reinstall conda. I have done both and I dont understand why it would be an environment issue and not a code issue... So,

I am wondering why I would get different results when applying a column by column pct_change()?

Comment: I do not see a difference, so perhaps it is still an install problem. Have you tried it in a standalone environment using something like virtualenv?

Comment: need sample data here, pandas version